# Proof $E$ field is path independent

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, coordinate-systems, maxwell-equations, conservative-field

[image]

From fundamentals I am trying to prove $E$ field is Conservative. Without the use of spherical coordinates, purely in cartesian as I have no knowledge of the spherical gradient. or the spherical line element. Given $dl$ is spherical coordinated it is easy. however I am having trouble deriving an expression for a line integral in cartesian. My attempt:

I have transformed everything into cartesian. however I seem so get that the line integral of $E dl$ from $a$ to $b$ is 3x the actual value as my last expression is repeated 3 times for each component of the electric field $L$. what have I done wrong?

Comment: Hi Jensen, site policy is to use MathJax to typeset equations rather than sharing images of handwritten text. If you need a tutorial, you can find one [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show that the integral of the $E$-field along any path from $a$ to $b$ is independent of the path taken. Consider a path $\vec{r}(\lambda) = (x(\lambda), y(\lambda), z(\lambda)$ for some parameter $\lambda$. Suppose further that $\vec{r}(0) = a$ and $\vec{r}(1) = b$.

Your first steps are correct: We may indeed write the integral of the electric field as
$$ \int_a^b \vec{E} \cdot d \vec{r}. $$
However, your next steps are not quite correct, since when you write $\int_a^b E_x dx$, you are integrating $E$ (which is a function of $x, y, z$) only along the $x$-direction instead of along the path $\vec{r}(\lambda)$ as you should.

You can fix this problem by doing everything parametrically in terms of $\lambda$. You can write
$$ \int_a^b \vec{E}(\vec{r}) \cdot \vec{dr} = \int_0^1 \vec{E}(\vec{r}(\lambda)) \cdot \frac{d\vec{r}}{d\lambda} d\lambda. $$
Write
$$ \vec{E}(\vec{r}(\lambda)) = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{(x(\lambda), y(\lambda), z(\lambda))}{(x(\lambda)^2 + y(\lambda)^2 + z(\lambda)^2 )^{3/2}} . $$
We then see that
$$ \vec{E}(\vec{r}(\lambda)) \cdot \frac{d\vec{r}}{d\lambda} = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{1}{(x(\lambda)^2 + y(\lambda)^2 + z(\lambda)^2 )^{3/2}} \left[ x(\lambda) \frac{dx}{d\lambda} + y(\lambda) \frac{dy}{d\lambda} + z(\lambda) \frac{dz}{d\lambda} \right] . $$
Using the chain rule, this is just
$$ \frac{d}{d\lambda} \left[ -\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{1}{ (x(\lambda)^2 + y(\lambda)^2 + z(\lambda)^2 )^{1/2}} \right]. $$
The integration now becomes easy:
$$ \int_0^1 \vec{E}(\vec{r}(\lambda)) \cdot \frac{d\vec{r}}{d\lambda} d\lambda = \left[ -\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{1}{ (x(\lambda)^2 + y(\lambda)^2 + z(\lambda)^2 )^{1/2}} \right]_0^1  $$
$$ = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_a^2 + y_a^2 + z_a^2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_b^2 + y_b^2 + z_b^2}}   \right] ,  $$
which is what you want.

Comment: thank you for your answer on solving this using a generalised parameterised path. I'll most likely accept this answer. however why can't I do it the way that I showed? obviously intuitively yes, I'm integrating a multivariable function with respect to 1 variable. but what step is actually Incorrect. I's  Integral(ex dx +eydy +ezdy) correct. and when I break it into multiple.integrals it becomes wrong. How can I solve It without parameterization as if I were to use spherical coordinates. the way I did it would work as the dot product reduced it to a singular integral with respect to dr.

Comment: mathematically speaking dr =dx i+dy j+dz k is still correct and doting it with the E field should still be correct. so why does it break down.

Comment: The issue is that the y-coordinate and z-coordinates are also changing as you integrate along dx — your expression doesn’t take this into account

Comment: Intuitively this makes sense. however   the line element regardless is dx I + dy j +dz k and doting it with E does give you integral(ex dx + eydy + ez dz) why is this dot product wrong mathematically  as this is exactly equivalent to Integral ( e . r'(t)dt) I think the issue is with separating them

Comment: It’s not the integrand that’s problematic, it’s the integration itself. When you integrate over Ex dx, you are integrating a function of a single variable over the interval from xa to xb. However, y and z are also changing from ya to yb along this interval, so in this sense y and z depend on x implicitly, so Ex dx is actually not a total deviative. Only the combination Ex dx + Ey dy + Ez dz is, as I showed.

Answer (score -1):

This is a good jumping off point for Maxwell's equations, albeit in a restricted form this early on. In the absence of a time varying magnetic field, $\nabla \times \vec{E}=0$, i.e. the curl of the electric field is zero. It can be proven that if the curl of a vector field vanishes everywhere, it can be represented as the gradient of a scalar potential,[General Principle of Conservative field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638099/why-curl-free-field-implies-existence-of-potential-function/638211) . Typically $\vec{E}=-\nabla V$ where V is the electric potential.

This is closely related to [Stoke's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem).

By the Fundamental Theorem of Line Integrals, the line integral of a gradient between two end points is equal to the change in the scalar function who's gradient you are using between those two points, or more generally $df=\nabla f \cdot d\vec{s}$ where f is the scalar function and $d\vec{s}$ is the line element. Since a function doesn't change leaving and then returning to the same point, the value of the integral is zero and path independent. This is regardless of many specifics of the electric field, just so long as it's irrotational, i.e. the curl is zero.